Laplacian matrix for a multi graph
Consier a multigraph $G=(V,E)$ with possible multiple edges between two vertices but no loops.
I am wondering what a Laplacian matrix could look like. A somewhat naive approach is simply to put as usual the degree of each vertex on the diagonal (counted with multiplicity of edges between the same vertices) and on the off-diagonals the negative of the number of edges between the corresponding vertices. Is this correct? and is there a source for it? I did not find anything in the literature.

Your definition:
$$L_{ij} = \begin{cases}-m_{ij} &\text{ if } i\neq j\\ \text{d}_i &\text{ else } \end{cases}$$
where $m_{ij}$ is the multiplicity of the edges between $i$ and $j$, is the most common way to define the laplacian matrix for multigraphs.
It is equivalent to the Laplacian for weighted graphs, where you take as a weight the multiplicity of the edges.
It has several good properties:

We can still define the Laplacian as $II^T$ where $I$ is the incidence matrix
The Matrix-tree theorem (which relates the number of spanning trees to the determinant of the Laplacian) generalizes for multigraphs
The bounds obtained for algebraic connectivity will still hold in general
The spectral properties generalize well

